# How to filter response data in nestJs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, jsonschema, nest

I am new to nestJs, Before I would learn nestJs, I have learnt fastify. In fastify, If I want to filter the response data I would define JSON Schema. it will filter out my server response data. But in nestJs I don't know how to do that. Even If I have define the JSON schema. Then the filtered data only shown in swagger. and it doesn't work to filter data unlike fastify. It will be cause for more security issue.

For Ex: There is an API,Which is used to create user, When that API is called, an user will be created. And the server will send the user data to that API response. In my case the server will send all data about created user including password. If I want to remove the password from response. I need to manualy frame the object. But in fastify, which is automaticaly handles the response depends on JSON schema. here my question is, this is possible in nest js

Friend, If you please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`Serializtion`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) of the response. You'd create a response model of your API, similar to a schema but class based with the appropraite `class-transformer` decorators, and return an instance of that class from your API, letting the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` handle serializing the response for you